# Include count result depending on value in group_by

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL table to store trip books. This table contains (among others) the following fields:

```
'trip_id' int(10) --> Foreign key to trip table
'departure_id' int(10) --> Foreign key to departure table
'book_category_id' int(10) --> Foreign key to type_of_book table
'customer_id' int(10) --> Foreign key to customer table
```

A book is defined by a trip and a departure, and it's included into a category. I need to count how many books there are for each category.

In the following example

```
trip_id  departure_id  book_category_id  customer_id    
-------  ------------  ----------------  -----------
1        1             1                 1
1        2             2                 2
2        1             1                 3
1        1             2                 4
2        1             1                 5
```

there would be 5 books in total:

- "Trip 1" (trip_id=1 and departure_id=1) has 1 book of category 1 and 1 book of category 2
- "Trip 2" (trip_id=1 and departure_id=2) has 1 book of category 2
- "Trip 3" (trip_id=2 and departure_id=1) has 2 books of category 1

I've tried running the following query:

```
SELECT `books`.`trip_id`, `books`.`departure_id`, COUNT(*) AS total_books
FROM (`books`)
GROUP BY `books`.`departure_id`
```

and, obviusly, I only get the total books for each trip:

```
trip_id  departure_id  total_books      
-------  ------------  -----------
1        1             2
1        2             1
2        1             2
```

How could I get a column showing the total books for category 1 and another column showing the total books for category 2?

```
trip_id  departure_id  total_books_category_1  total_books_category_2      
-------  ------------  ----------------------  ----------------------
1        1             1                       1
1        2             0                       1
2        1             0                       2
```

Thanks in advance :)